# Visual Studio IDE - Find and Replace Prevent Jumping to Next Result?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, find-replace

Is there any workaround or extension to prevent Visual Studio IDE 2022 from scrolling my view when clicking the "Replace Next" button in the Find-and-Replace related windows?

I use REGEX code with Find-and-Replace, and so I would like to verify that text is replaced correctly each time I press the "Replace Next" button. But the view scrolls or switches to another file with the next matching found result before I can see the changes that were made.

I also like to run Visual Studio's "Edit.FormatDocument" command to beautify or clean up the improper indenting made when replacing text, but I can't do that to my current file before Visual Studio jumps to the next matching result in another file.

It would be fantastic to temporarily turn off that auto-scroll-to-next-result behavior or to have another button in the Find-and-Replace windows that replaces the current matching text without scrolling to the next one.

I looked into making my own Visual Studio extension to override the behavior or to make a custom find and replace command but it's difficult to find examples for doing something like this and I'm just a beginner. I wasn't even able to get something working with the [DTE.Find.FindReplace API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.find.findreplace). And with the addition of the extension needing to be compatible with REGEX I figure it will be more difficult.

Thank you for any input or assistance with this.

Comment: The focus moving of searching/replacing is a very common behavior, not only VS using this, but also many other apps. I think even extension is also hard/unable to achieve this, this is a very basic behavior. You can take a look whether the workaround I shared can accept by you. If I misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any workaround or extension to prevent Visual Studio IDE 2022
> from scrolling my view when clicking the "Replace Next" button in the
> Find-and-Replace related windows?

**The answer is NO.**

For the focus of the "Replace Next" feature, Visual Studio doesn't have such configuration to control this. And also doesn't have such an already-made extension.

And I think extenion also hard/unable to achieve this. I didn't see any API of VS SDK give such configuration.

If you don't want to see the results via scrolling the view. what about "find all" feature:

[image]

If you don't want focus move when click "replace next", what about "replace all" feature:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, the "Replace all" button doesn't allow me to preview the changes for each replacement made which is what I need to ensure the replacement worked correctly each time since I'm using REGEX (regular expressions) in the Find and Replace input fields. And the "Find All" button doesn't carry out the replacement which means I have to manually make it myself which defeats the purpose and the time savings part of using REGEX.